# Simple yet realistic billiard ball acceleration

Tags: c++, c, game-physics, physics

I have a simple 2D game of pool. You can give a ball some speed, and it'll move around and hit other balls. But I want a ball to stop eventually, so I added some acceleration, by running this code every frame:

```
balls[i].ax = -balls[i].vx * 0.1;
balls[i].ay = -balls[i].vy * 0.1;
...
if(hypot(balls[i].vx, balls[i].vy) < 0.2){
    balls[i].vx = 0;
    balls[i].vy = 0;
}
```

And it works... But I find it weird, not realistic. I have no physics knowledge, but I'm pretty sure friction should not depend on speed.

How can I improve physics of slowing down without too much complexity?

Comment: *I have no physics knowledge* - How about you learn some? https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/physics-of-billiards.html And there is much more by simply querying "physics of billiard" and you can add "friction" to it to be more specific.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be purely a question about physics - "how should I accurately model this real world physical system?" - and not at all about how to write the actual code. Please try https://physics.stackexchange.com. Alternately: since you apparently know that `friction` is the name of the force in question, try using a search engine to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) that.

Comment: Once the ball is properly rolling the main mechanism for stopping is air resistance. which can be model as precisely proportional to the velocity. If the surface is bumpy it also contributes but at the end of the day you can claim generically the same.

Comment: @alfC air resistance is a square law, and anyway more likely the nap of the cloth (and the coefficient of restitution between other balls or the side cushsion).

Comment: Right, I stand corrected. I wanted to make the point opposite to OP's "I'm pretty sure friction should not depend on speed." and anyway the resistance is complicated, it depends in the regime and turbulence. Since this is a game, the OP has to add a friction force that is a function of velocity (that for sure) and try difference simple function until one "looks right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rolling friction formula is this: F_k,r​=μ_k,r_​Fn. It only factors in the properties of the surface (μ_k) and the force on the ball (r_​Fn). This should decelerate with a constant value, just adjust it until it looks roughly correct.

Example code:

```
x = 1 // mess around with this until it looks right
if (ball.xVelocity > x) { ball.xVelocity -= x } else { ball.xVelocity = 0 }
if (ball.yVelocity > x) { ball.yVelocity -= x } else { ball.yVelocity = 0 }
```

Comment: not the the call can now move only in one direction, use `abs(ball.xVelocity) > x`